# How do I share files between MacbookPro over WAN to my PC over LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, macbook-pro, desktop-computer, wired-networking

I have a wireless router set up, connected to the internet through a modem through LAN, connected to my PC through LAN, and connected to my Macbook Pro via WAN. [Here's a rough image of the network map](http://puu.sh/286TT)

I have enabled filesharing on my MBP and PC, but they doesn't seem to detect each other. Is it possible to share datas between my MBP and PC through 2 different networks? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide : http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568 using the SMB command and the IP address of the windows computer. This should give you more hints. Paste in here the exact reason of why it is failing if that helps.

Your network diagram is great but its largely irrelevant - essentially each device is on the same LAN and the wireless router is basically just a switch between them (for all intents and purposes).

Comment: They doesn't even detect each other; pinging to the other device's IP address fails for both device. However when connected with LAN, they detect each other and I can send files via ftp.
The current problem is why both devices are not detecting each other, if one is over LAN, and the other is over WAN. Thanks.

Comment: Please stop using the words LAN and WAN and describe what you mean. Are you trying to do file sharing over the internet? I'm working off the picture you attached but maybe you are now saying sometimes the laptop moves offsite and tries to connect via the internet? Just use simple English and explain the use case.

Comment: I am trying to share files locally, without the use of internet.
Imagine that the internet router does not exist. The pc is connected to a wireless hub locally ( with wires ), and the other device ( mbp ) is connected to the wireless hub _wirelessly_, without wires. However, I found out that they don't even seem to detect each other.
If it can find each other, sharing files would be possible, how do I make these 2 devices able to connect or detect each other?